# Heroku failed to bind to $PORT (react/vite)

Tags: reactjs, heroku, deployment, vite

**Error**

```
2022-06-18T15:22:38.901239+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Error R10 (Boot timeout) -> Web process failed to bind to $PORT within 60 seconds of launch

2022-06-18T15:22:38.948973+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Stopping process with SIGKILL

2022-06-18T15:22:39.281456+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to crashed

2022-06-18T15:21:37.000000+00:00 app[api]: Build succeeded
```

**package.json**

```
{
  "name": "pzcomparre",
  "private": true,
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "scripts": {
    "dev": "vite",
    "build": "tsc && vite build",
    "start": "vite",
    "postcss-run": "postcss ./public/index.css --dir public --watch"
  },

  "dependencies": {
    "react": "^18.0.0",
    "react-dom": "^18.0.0",
    "react-router-dom": "^6.3.0"
  },

  "devDependencies": {
    "@types/react": "^18.0.0",
    "@types/react-dom": "^18.0.0",
    "@vitejs/plugin-react": "^1.3.0",
    "autoprefix": "^1.0.1",
    "autoprefixer": "^10.4.7",
    "cssnano": "^5.1.11",
    "postcss": "^8.4.14",
    "postcss-cli": "^9.1.0",
    "typescript": "^4.6.3",
    "vite": "^2.9.9"
  },

  "engines": {
    "node": "^16.15.1",
    "npm": "^8.12.2"
  }
}
```

I first had a problem where the start script was not working so I set both of these configs (NPM_CONFIG_PRODUCTION, YARN_PRODUCTION) to false, now I am having this error... any help is appreciated!